# Issue with restrict limit characters & restrict special charecters in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am creating a OTP Screen on that screen i have added 6 text fields.Now i want to restrict to enter only ONE charecter & also want to restrict user not to enter any special charecters.Below is the code i have used,Please review the code & let me know what is wrong ?

```
let notAllowedCharacters = "!@#$%^&*()_+{},./[]?:;";

 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        if newLength <= 1 {

            return true
        }
        else {
            let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: notAllowedCharacters);
            let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: set as CharacterSet).joined(separator: "")
            return filtered == string;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the control of your `NSCharacterSet` when you make the check for the characters length. Otherwise it will always be true regardless character if there is always one character. Update your code to the following and it will work for you:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length

    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: notAllowedCharacters)
    if newLength <= 1 && !(string.rangeOfCharacter(from: set as CharacterSet) != nil) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```